# How to LiveBind Firemonkey TListbox that has a Custom Style?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, livebindings

Following the EMB example "Custom List" found in "RAD Studio\12.0\Samples\FireMonkey\CustomListBox"

It demonstrated by code how to have Items customized on the ListBox.

Inserting one Item on the TListBox by code:

```
  // create custom item
  Item := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
  Item.Parent := ListBox1;
  Item.StyleLookup := 'CustomItem';
  Item.Text := 'item ' + IntToStr(Item.Index); // set filename
  if Odd(Item.Index) then
    Item.ItemData.Bitmap := Image1.Bitmap // set thumbnail
  else
    Item.ItemData.Bitmap := Image2.Bitmap; // set thumbnail
  Item.StylesData['resolution'] := '1024x768 px'; // set size
  Item.StylesData['depth'] := '32 bit';
  Item.StylesData['visible'] := true; // set Checkbox value
```

I want to do the same using LiveBinding exclusively.

I could success show the style and bind some of the items:

[image: TListBox with Customized Items]

And some of the LiveBindings (using a prototype):

[image: LiveBinding]

And this is a piece of the custom style from the delphi example:

[image: Custom Style]

My questions:

1. How can I access the other 3 defined items to fill up with data?
2. How can I get the event from the Button and CheckBox (both going to same event handler)
3. How can I make that works in a frame? There is no working StyleBook component at design time

Bonus question :)

Is it possible to have all above working with a StyleBook exclusive for this kind of need? (a StyleBook that holds all and only TListBoxItems Sytles?) , so no messing with the StyleBook that is the form´s defined.